# Copy list object in python in recursive function - Strange behaviour

Tags: python, list, recursion

This recursive function:

```
myGrid = [[0,0,0],
          [0,0,0],
          [0,0,0]]

def testchange(grid, number=-1, number2=0):
    kgrid = list(grid)
    kgrid[number][number2] = 2
    number += 1
    number2 += 1
    if number < 2:
        print '1', kgrid
        testchange(kgrid,number,number2)
        print '2', kgrid
        testchange(kgrid,number+1,number2)

testchange(myGrid);
```

prints out:

```
1 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0]]
1 [[0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0]]
2 [[0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0]]
2 [[0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 2]]
```

in my function after I first call testchange() kgrid should not be changed, but as you can see it is, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy `grid`, use [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy). Otherwise a shallow copy is made, leading to the behaviour you describe.